# ANGULAR: How to extend an abstract class two levels with generics

Tags: angular, class, typescript-generics

I am trying to extend a class with two levels of inheritance with generics, like the following diagram:

[image]

First attempt, I declared `BaseResourceTableComponent` as extending `BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel>`:

```javascript
export abstract class BaseResourceModel {
    public id?: number;
}

export abstract class BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel> {
  public resources: T[] = [];
  ...
}

export abstract class BaseResourceTableComponent extends BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel>  { // <--- ERROR!
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T>;
  ...
}

// now, the non abstract classes

export class User extends BaseResourceModel {
  constructor(
    public name?: string,
  ) {
    super();
  }

export class UserTableComponent extends BaseResourceTableComponent<User> {
  ...
}
```

I get the following error:

***error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.***

Second attempt, I declared `BaseResourceTableComponent` as extending `BaseResourceListComponent<BaseResourceModel>` (without the `T extents`):

```javascript
export abstract class BaseResourceModel {
    public id?: number;
}

export abstract class BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel> {
  public resources: T[] = [];
  ...
}

export abstract class BaseResourceTableComponent extends BaseResourceListComponent<BaseResourceModel>  {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BaseResourceModel>;
  ...
}

// now, the non abstract classes

export class User extends BaseResourceModel {
  constructor(
    public name?: string,
  ) {
    super();
  }

export class UserTableComponent extends BaseResourceTableComponent<User> { // <--- ERROR!
  ...
}
```

It passes, no error in the `BaseResourceTableComponent` declaration but I get the following error further on `UserTableComponent` declaration:

***error TS2315: Type 'BaseResourceTableComponent' is not generic.***

I am really confused here!

Am I missing something? Workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export abstract class BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel> {
  public resources: T[] = [];
  ...
}
```

Here you define the `BaseResourceListComponent` class with a generic type `T extends BaseResourceModel`. The `extends BaseResourceModel` part is a **type constraint** which imposes restrictions on the types `T` can have. What this means is that `T` must either be `BaseResourceModel` or one of its **subtypes**.
A type `B` is a **subtype** of `A` if `B` is of type `A` and has additional information(i.e: **properties**, **methods**).

```js
export abstract class BaseResourceTableComponent extends BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel>  { // <--- ERROR!
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T>;
  ...
}
```

Here you get an error because `BaseResourceListComponent` expects a type, and here you provide `T extends BaseResourceModel`, but you haven't defined `T` at all.

You could solve it with

```js
export abstract class BaseResourceTableComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel> extends BaseResourceListComponent<T> { }
```

Now, `T` is a type, no matter if it's concrete or generic, as long as `T` fulfills the constraint: `extends BaseResourceModel`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=117&pln=9&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAIQOACVgUIBXKTYAWQgBNhc4BvAKDj7jA0kuAJaY4IlgH4AXHAB2NALZJgUANzcAvt26hIsRKnRYc%20QiTKVqdBgBkRaAMIQlkecHkwAPABU4oDCeLESkKBRUtPRMrOwAfFy8AkKi4lCRtlRyvgDaALpwALxw%20Zo6euDQ8MhoGNhweAShVhnRvsi4wC5uEB5efgEgQfIhluHWUQzMbLgJgcHN4632jjDd7p4%20vgk8fCwIMAgAypPA2UVwAOSXiEQ08gDW8hAA7vK3cL5lugD0PwqvAA0cBgAAtgAD3jUTPVGoQqLp9FUGuYiABVcJQQbDUZhCI2aLTdiJPiYXq1GjYaAACiSfEEwjECgQSmAsjgtRE8gA5oCkgBKEn8FA0MBqan8zR8HTlJGGOHozHtYRdVwbLzYhZjfGnZWdda9TbeDFqHbabhAA)

Answer (score 0):

Both of your problems are caused by BaseResourceTableComponent not being declared generic.

`export abstract class BaseResourceTableComponent extends BaseResourceListComponent<T extends BaseResourceModel>` says that the generic parameter for `BaseResourceListComponent` is `T`, but doesn't give anyway to determine what `T` is because `BaseResourceTableComponent` neither specifies a concrete parameter nor gives a way to declare a generic parameter that can be essentially passed down to the parent class.

Extending a generic class does not make the class doing the extending generic; In fact, you're trying to rely on exactly that with `export class UserTableComponent extends BaseResourceTableComponent<User>`.